# LESS: generate different CSSs for different theme (color variation)

Tags: less

I would like to manage creation of different "theme" for my site, using LESS.

My idea is to generate different compiled .css files, using each time a specific variable.less that is imported by root file.

Here a simple example:

1) I have 2 different color scheme in 2 distinct files: `variable1.less` and `variable2.less`.

2) A file `style.les`s should have an @import rule like "`@import variableX.less`" and obviously this *'X' should change assuming values '1' and '2'*.

3) Compiler should then generate `style1.css` and `style2.css`, each based on relative `variable1.less` and `variable2.less`.

How to obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip your import directions.

The `style.less` file should not import any variables.

Instead, each `variableN.less` file should import `style.less` after defining all of its variables.
These files will then each compile to a full set of rules based on their variable values.

Comment: ehi... it seems the Coulumbus' egg :D But in this way... I have to compile each of them separatly, right? Is there no way to compile a single `.less` file but obtain 2 `.css` files ?

Comment: @LucaDetomi: No.  But you could import `style.less` into two different `body.SomeTheme` selectors to generate two themes in the same file.

Comment: Yes, I knew this last proposal, but my intent is to create 2 different files because I don't provide a change theme on-the-fly, so it's better to load only one .css file per each theme, instead of a bigger single one.